# Passing options to template function in thor

Tags: ruby, templates, erb, thor

I am looking for a way to pass options to the ERB templating engine in thors template action.

I stumbled upon the bundler cli source where thors template action is being used like this:

```
opts = {:name => name, 
    :constant_name => constant_name, 
    :constant_array => constant_array, 
    :author_name => author_name, 
    :author_email => author_email
}

template(File.join("newgem/Gemfile.tt"),
           File.join(target, "Gemfile"),
            opts)
```

But when I add options like this in my thor tasks they are not found by ERB, i can only use arguments and functions in my thor class to set variables in the template.

I have no clue how binding works in ruby, maybe there is a way to pass a scope through binding to ERB.

Comment: What code did you try in your Thor file that didn't work?

Comment: I did copy the code above and it didn't catch the passed options.

Answer (score 14):

By using instance variables, it should work.

```
@name = name
template("source","target")
```

My template looks like this:

```
<test><%= @name %></test>
```

This works for me. I haven't tried the passing of specific values.

Answer (score 12):

I can't find any documentation to answer this, but reading through the source of the Bundler CLI, it appears that if you were trying to reference the :author_email parameter inside the template,

```
Author email: <%= config[:author_email] %>
```

works.

Comment: This work for me too. The hash of `opts` passed to `template` is called `config` in the Erb template.